# Wildfly 10 - UT000124: renegotiation timed out

Tags: ssl, wildfly, client-certificates, undertow

So this error has brought development to a complete halt. I'm using client certificate authentication and I keep seeing this error in the logs and for no obvious reason. Granted, I don't have a lot of other information to supply... The wildly config I'm using locally works but intermittently gives this same error.

```
4:06:02,521 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-32) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ppi/whoami: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000124: renegotiation timed out
at io.undertow.server.ConnectionSSLSessionInfo.renegotiateNoRequest(ConnectionSSLSessionInfo.java:175)
at io.undertow.server.ConnectionSSLSessionInfo.renegotiate(ConnectionSSLSessionInfo.java:89)
at io.undertow.security.impl.ClientCertAuthenticationMechanism.getPeerCertificates(ClientCertAuthenticationMechanism.java:125)
at io.undertow.security.impl.ClientCertAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(ClientCertAuthenticationMechanism.java:92)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:233)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:250)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:219)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:121)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:96)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:89)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

A google search on that exception message brings up only one result... Any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Blessings,
Brian

Comment: It might be useful to try and post some code to help us debug your problem

Comment: I know... Ordinarily I would do so... But I'm not even reaching my code yet. This exception happens on TLS negotiation and is buried in the undertow ssl code. I'd be happy to post the code where this exception is being thrown, if that would help.

Comment: @Brian Call Any news here?